# Grandpa and his silly questions. Another Grandpa mystery

Tags: riddle

An entry into the [Topical Challenge #41 Short and Sweet](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6502/fortnightly-topic-challenge-41-short-and-sweet)

Grandpa was in one of his very silly "puzzling" mood.

> "There is only one answer to the following", he quipped.
>
> "Take a number between 0 and 9,
>
> Split it into 3 to 2 ratio,
>
> And there it is! follow me?"
>
> "Only one answer?" I asked
>
> "Yes. Get it?" He says with a smile.

I don't. Do you?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a number between 0 and 9, Split it into 3 to 2 ratio,

> A number between 0 and 9 is a digit, which split 3:2, is **dig it**.

"And there it is! follow me?", ... , "Yes. Get it?"

> And there *it* is! follow me? → showing *it*, and *follow me* means *dig it*
>  "Yes. Get *it*?" → *it*

Above is missing an explanation for the 'only one answer' parts, which kanoo does [mathematically](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/75308/19547).

Answer (score 4):

Is the answer

> 0

Because

> Grandpa said 'There it is' after performing the 3:2 ratio math, as though implying the number originally selected was seen again. The only number that can multiply or divide by any other rational number and still be itself is 0.

Comment: this makes more sense :-)

Answer (score 2):

Well isn't it

> 3 and 2

because

> only 5 is divisible by 5, so it's the only one that can be split 3-to-2, so the result can only be 3 and 2.

This is marked 'short and sweet'... but even so, that seems too easy. And there's the point that

> mathematically, 0 is also divisible by 5, so 0 and 0 should also be an answer. And there's only supposed to be one answer. However, mathematical convention about degenerate cases often does not apply to english words, so this might not count as a split.

Comment: Can't you rot13(fcyvg nal ahzore va n 3 gb 2 engvb?  vg whfg znl abg or na vagrtre nafjre.)

Comment: @SteveV right rot13(na vagrtre) was not specified.